# How to count only letters in a string?

Tags: c#, mysql

At the next code I'm splitting text to words, inserting them into a table separately and counting the numbers of letters in each word.
The problem is that counter is also counting spaces at the beginning of each line, and give me wrong value for some of the words.
How can I count only the letters of each word exactly?

```
var str = reader1.ReadToEnd();

char[] separators = new char[] {' ', ',', '/', '?'};   //Clean punctuation from copying
var words = str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray(); //Insert all the song words into "words" string
string constring1 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=123";

using (var conDataBase1 = new MySqlConnection(constring1))
{
    conDataBase1.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        int numberOfLetters = words[i].ToCharArray().Length; //Calculate the numbers of letters in each word  
        var songtext = "insert into myproject.words (word_text,word_length) values('" + words[i] + "','" + numberOfLetters + "');"; //Insert words list and length into words table
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase1 = new MySqlCommand(songtext, conDataBase1);
        try
        { 
            cmdDataBase1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is it only spaces you are having issues with ?   If so .Trim() the string first.

Comment: If you're splitting and removing empty entries, i can't seem to see any reason why it should give you any spaces, maybe you can share with us the entire line and what it has been split into ?

Comment: How do you want to count "letters" that take more than one `char` (like surrogate pairs or de-normalized accented characters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a simple and fast way of doing so:

```
int numberOfLetters = words[i].Count(word => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(word));
```

Another simple solution that will save you the above and rest of the answers here, will be to `Trim()` first, and than do your normal calculation, due your statement that it is happening just in the beginning of every line.

```
var words = str.Trim().Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Than all you will need is: (Without the redundant conversion)

```
int numberOfLetters = words[i].Length;
```

Comment: I think you're mixing stuff and it's a different issue not concerning with Counting non white spaces. Make a new Post, but first i would recomend you to put some `Console.WriteLine` output on the word your inserting to see if it really the problem or it something in your code. Additionally, It is customary to mark the Answer that helped you the best + Upvote it as well.

Comment: Thanks, the fist solution is working, but I still have a two problems. The last word at each line appeares at the table with the first word of the next line. I can avoid that by entering space at the end of each line. The second problem, it also counting 0 length for empty words.

Comment: I don't know which `StreamReader` you used on when applied `ReadToEnd` i assumed it read till the end of the line, thus you don't need to "handle" the last word with appending a space on the end, because split doing stuff for you. double check yourself to see if `str` represent 1 line, If not, then you should rethink how you want to handle a case of 2 lines that have been read by the `ReadToEnd`.

Comment: Acctually, I'm reading full text (song text). Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

See [String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int numberOfLetters = words[i].Trim().ToCharArray().Length; //Calculate the numbers of letters in each word
```

Comment: I still have a problem. The last word at each line appeares at the table with the first word of the next line.

Comment: Sounds like you're not splitting by newline character.  See if adding `\n` to your `separators` works.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `' '` use `'\s+'` since it matches one or more whitespace at once, so it splits on any number of whitespace characters.

```
Regex.Split(myString, @"\s+");
```